# Images not showing up after uploading to s3 with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to find out why my pictures are not showing up on S3.  When I inspect the (non-existant) picture, it shows the correct amazon s3 path, but the image is never uploaded into s3.  When I type heroku logs --tail into my console, there's no obvious error.  I also already set the s3 variables on heroku.  The heroku logs look identical to my other website that uploads music files, but the files never show up on S3...

Here's the [github](https://github.com/sunwooz/RestaurantCMS) page if you prefer to read it there. Thanks!

Heroku Logs after uploading. The only discernible difference I see from my other app is that this app redirects first, and then paperclip saves attatchments.

```
Started POST "/restaurants/3/menuitems" for 68.38.119.33 at 2013-01-25 16:36:07 +0000
2013-01-25T16:36:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MenuitemsController#create as HTML
2013-01-25T16:36:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"I8iVlAdNa/ui96aflFAlPxfAIgmvOB4k/Y7Fhf5ElMI=", "menuitem"=>{"name"=>"Penne alla Vodkas", "description"=>"Fresh oven baked bread with a kiss of mother nature cut into fresh little delicious strips.", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005ff55f0 @original_filename="penneallavodka.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"menuitem[image]\"; filename=\"penneallavodka.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130125-2-1xa5s3v>>, "price"=>"10.95"}, "commit"=>"Add Item", "restaurant_id"=>"3"}
2013-01-25T16:36:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://sugarcider.com/restaurants/3
2013-01-25T16:36:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 4129ms (ActiveRecord: 18.1ms)
2013-01-25T16:36:11+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Saving attachments.
2013-01-25T16:36:11+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving penneallavodka.jpeg
2013-01-25T16:36:11+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 200 4.101325 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"restaurantimages",:content_length=>818276,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>#<Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter:0x00000006322908 @target=#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005ff55f0 @original_filename="penneallavodka.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"menuitem[image]\"; filename=\"penneallavodka.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130125-2-1xa5s3v>>, @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/penneallavodka20130125-2-mfgg7i.jpeg>>,:key=>"penneallavodka.jpeg")
```

Menuitem model

```
class Menuitem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :price, :image

  belongs_to :restaurant

  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => {
      :thumbnail => '100x101>',
      :regular => '560x568>'
    },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    },
    :path => ":filename.:extension"
end
```

New.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@restaurant, @restaurant.menuitems.new], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %><br/>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br/>
  <%= f.label :description %><br/>
  <%= f.text_field :description %><br/>
  <%= f.label :image %><br/>
  <%= f.file_field :image %><br/>
  <%= f.label :price %><br/>
  <%= f.text_field :price %><br/>
  <%= f.submit 'Add Item', :class => 'btn btn-large btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

Menuitems_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @menuitem = @restaurant.menuitems.build
  end

  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @menuitem = @restaurant.menuitems.build(params[:menuitem])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @menuitem.save
        format.html { redirect_to restaurant_path(@restaurant) }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to restaurant_path(@restaurant), notice: 'One or more fields are not correctly formatted.' }
      end
    end
  end

  def index
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @menuitems = @restaurant.menuitems.build
  end
```

I have this in production.rb

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_protocol => 'http',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

restaurant's index.html

```
  <% @menuitems.each do |f| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.name %></td>
      <td><%= f.description %></td>
      <td>$<%= f.price %></td>
      <td><%= image_tag f.image.url(:regular) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', restaurant_menuitem_path(f), :method => :delete, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_restaurant_menuitem_path(f), :class => 'btn btn-success'%></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my own problem.

I had to delete my original bucket and make a new bucket with a new name, then I had to reset my aws_bucket variable on heroku config with

```
heroku config:add AWS_BUCKET=newbucketname
```

Now it works perfectly!

Comment: why to delete old one ??